# How to change VLABEL on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I want to change vlabel of vertex.

```
agens=# create (:v1{id:1})-[:e1{id:3}]->(:v1{id:2});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 2, INSERT EDGE 1)
agens=# match (n:v1{id:1}) set n:v2 remove n:v1;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: match (n:v1{id:1}) set n:v2 remove n:v1;
                                ^
```

But, there is an error on it.

How to change VLABEL on AgensGraph?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change label on vertex on AgensGraph.

But, You can try add new vertex with same properties and remove old vertex.

```
agens=# create (:v1{id:1})-[:e1{id:3}]->(:v1{id:2});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 2, INSERT EDGE 1)
agens=# match p = ( (n1)-[r1]->(n2) ) return p;
                               p                               
---------------------------------------------------------------
 [v1[3.1]{"id": 1},e1[4.1][3.1,3.2]{"id": 3},v1[3.2]{"id": 2}]
(1 row)

agens=# match (n1:v1{id:1})-[r1:e1]->(n2) create (n3:v2)-[r2:e1]->(n2) set n3 = properties(n1), r2 = properties(r1) delete r1, n1;
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 1, DELETE VERTEX 1, DELETE EDGE 1, UPDATE PROPERTY 2)
agens=# match p = ( (n1)-[r1]->(n2) ) return p;
                               p                               
---------------------------------------------------------------
 [v2[5.1]{"id": 1},e1[4.2][5.1,3.2]{"id": 3},v1[3.2]{"id": 2}]
(1 row)
```